# Mysql - Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

Existe ya una pregunta pero la verdad es que no resuelve.
Mi problema es que me marca ese error en esta consulta

```
SELECT per_foto
FROM perfil
WHERE ( SELECT segi.per_id as 'JarhChuy'
    FROM seguidos as segi
    JOIN seguidores as segs ON ( segs.segs_id = segi.segs_id )
    WHERE segi.us_id = 1) 
    IN 
  ( SELECT us_id
    FROM juegos_usuarios as ju 
    JOIN juegos as j ON (j.jue_id = ju.jue_id)
    WHERE j.jue_id = 2)
```

y cada consulta me arroja id diferentes que al ser comparados quiero que me extraiga los que son igual

```
SELECT segi.per_id
FROM seguidos as segi 
JOIN seguidores as segs ON ( segs.segs_id = segi.segs_id )
WHERE segi.us_id = 1;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT us_id
FROM juegos_usuarios as ju 
JOIN juegos as j ON (j.jue_id = ju.jue_id)
WHERE j.jue_id = 2;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pues el error que muestra es retorna mas de 1 valor. Algún ayuda, consejo o algo

Comment: La parte izquierda de tu where no puede devolver mas de un registro, y es lo que esta pasando. al no entender la logica de lo que queres, es muy dificl ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que busco hacer es unir esas dos consultas y que solo me extraiga los valores repetidos  en este ejemplo 2 y 3 son los que me deberían aparecer al unir las tablas
Ya que estoy intentando traer cuales amigos(seguidos en mi caso) tiene el juego que seleccione.

Comment: Y que tiene que ver perfil con esas dos tablas? porque lo que vos queres hacer, se hace con un join entre las mismas...

Comment: El perfil es que tiene el nombre , foto, país, descripción del perfil y de ahí voy a extraer la foto de los amigos que tienen ese juego. No sé si tengas Steam pero  estoy replicando la biblioteca de steam de cuando seleccionas un juego salen tus amigos que tienen ese juego

Comment: Ok. Pero lo que leiste sigue siendo valido. Por lo que veo sabes hacer un join. Entonces lo que vos pones en el where, en realidad es una condicion de join. y falta que unas la tabla perfil con esas dos, no hay ninguna condicion de union. No puedo darte una respuesta porque faltan todas las relaciones entre las tablas.

Comment: Ok creo con lo hablado si tienes razon de la consulta del lado izquierdo, Ya la solucione solo poniendo us_id in en casa subconsulta y con eso basto

Comment: Que hacemos con la pregunta? porque asi como esta, no tiene una respuesta para darte

Comment: ya puse la corrección de mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Con ayuda de su conocimiento de "gbianchi♦" que fue que la primera subconsulta (la parte izquierda del where ) no puede devolver mas de un registro, y es lo que esta pasando. al no entender la logica

Es agregarle un campo que contenga lo que desees extraer en mi caso fue us_id de mi tabla perfil y al final mi consulta quedo de esta manera

```
SELECT per_foto
FROM perfil
WHERE us_id IN ( SELECT segi.per_id 
    FROM seguidos as segi
    JOIN seguidores as segs ON ( segs.segs_id = segi.segs_id )
    WHERE segi.us_id = 1) 
    AND us_id IN
  ( SELECT us_id
    FROM juegos_usuarios as ju 
    JOIN juegos as j ON (j.jue_id = ju.jue_id)
    WHERE j.jue_id = 2)
```

Comment: eh.. pero sigue estando mal.. aunque resuelva tu problema, es un query complejo e incorrecto.. que relacion hay entre perfil y esas tablas? y porque eso esta en el where? de donde sale us_id?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agrupar los resultados usando `group_concat` y en el filtro aplica `find_in_set` para localizar el valor que necesitas por si requieres filtrar en base al resultado que se retorna en forma de array separado con comas, puedes encontrar mas información en [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html).